# How to check if a folder exists before creating it in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to know if a folder exists before creating it, this is because I store pictures inside and I fear that the pictures are deleted if  overwrite the folder.
The code I have to create a folder is as follows

```
$path = public_path().'/images';
File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

See: [file_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Usage:

```
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    // path does not exist
}
```

In Laravel:

```
if(!File::exists($path)) {
    // path does not exist
}
```

> Note: In Laravel `$path` start from `public` folder, so if you want to check `'public/assets'` folder the `$path` = `'assets'`

Comment: Its much better to use File::ensureDirectoryExists(). It checks if directory exists and craete it if it does not

Answer (score 45):

With Laravel you can use:

```
$path = public_path().'/images';
File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
```

By the way, you can also put subfolders as argument in a Laravel path helper function, just like this:

```
$path = public_path('images/');
```

Comment: I like elegant use of `or` in this answer.

Comment: Works like a charm you just need to add   use File;   to the controller

Answer (score 37):

You can also call this method of File facade:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
File::ensureDirectoryExists('/path/to/your/folder')
```

which creates a folder if it does not exist and if exists, then does nothing

Comment: this method is available since Laravel v6.13.0

Comment: best solution for my problem!

Comment: Namespace for File method: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

Answer (score 11):

In Laravel 5.x/6 you can do it with [Storage Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/filesystem#retrieving-files):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$path = "path/to/folder/";

if(!Storage::exists($path)){
    Storage::makeDirectory($path);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Way -1 :

```
if(!is_dir($backupLoc)) {

    mkdir($backupLoc, 0755, true);
}
```

Way -2 :

```
if (!file_exists($backupLoc)) {

    mkdir($backupLoc, 0755, true);
}
```

Way -3 :

```
if(!File::exists($backupLoc)) {

    File::makeDirectory($backupLoc, 0755, true, true);
}
```

> Do not forget to use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

Way -4 :

```
if(!File::exists($backupLoc)) {

    Storage::makeDirectory($backupLoc, 0755, true, true);
}
```

> In this way you have to put the configuration first in config folder
>   filesystems.php . [Not recommended unless you are using external disks]

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way is to use

```
if (!File::exists($path))
{

}
```

See the [source code](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Filesystem.Filesystem.html#10-19)

If you look at the code, it's calling `file_exists()`

Answer (score 0):

I normally create random folders inside the images for each file this helps a bit in encrypting urls and thus public will find it hardr to view your files by simply typing the url to your directory.

```
// Check if Logo is uploaded and file in random folder name -  
if (Input::hasFile('whatever_logo'))
            {
                $destinationPath = 'uploads/images/' .str_random(8).'/';
                $file = Input::file('whatever_logo');
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();                
                $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                $savedPath = $destinationPath . $filename;
                $this->whatever->logo = $savedPath;
                $this->whatever->save();
            }

            // otherwise NULL the logo field in DB table.
            else 
            {
                $this->whatever->logo = NULL;    
                $this->whatever->save();    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works great for me

```
if(!File::exists($storageDir)){
    File::makeDirectory($storageDir, 0755, true, true);
    $img->save('Filename.'.png',90);
}
```